Why does high XIRR not equal to high portfolio return?
As per my understanding, if we invest the same amount in two different funds, the fund with the higher XIRR is always expected to generate more return compared to the fund with lower XIRR. The below calculation seems to be proving this wrong and I am not able to understand why.
Cashflow



Date
Fund A
Fund B




1-Jan-2020
100
100


1-Jan-2021
100
0


2-Jan-2022
100
0


3-Jan-2023
100
0


4-Jan-2024
100
0


4-Jan-2025
100
0


5-Jan-2026
100
0


6-Jan-2027
100
0


7-Jan-2028
100
0


7-Jan-2029
100
900


8-Jan-2030 (Withdrawing here)
-1200
-1100



Summary



Fund Name
XIRR
Total Invested
Total Gains




Fund B
4.662252547
1000
100


Fund A
3.280256454
1000
200



Fund A has generated higher returns but has a lower XIRR when compared to Fund B ? Aren't funds with low XIRR always supposed to generate lesser returns when compared to the ones with higher returns ?
PS: I got same XIRR values in both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel.

The difference has to do with the time value of money.  You may also want to check out answers to this question: Can you explain "time value of money" and "compound interest" and provide examples of each?
From Microsoft's documentation for XIRR:

Returns the internal rate of return for a schedule of cash flows that is not necessarily periodic.

The rate of return for Fund B over the whole period was indeed higher than in Fund A.  The initial $100 investment returned about $58 over the ten years, while the initial $100 in Fund A returned only about $38.
But in your example, the additional investments over that first $100 had more time to grow and compound in Fund A.  On the other hand, in Fund B, the additional investment had only one year to grow before everything was withdrawn.  The higher rate of return had less to compound over time.  In Fund A, the rate of return was lower, but it had a larger balance to compound for most of the life of the investment, therefore total returns were higher than in Fund B.
